# Mongoose Model Object behaves strangely

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am using mongoose to get person data from database. This is the code i use:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Person.findOne({}, (err, result) => {
      if(err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result.firstname);
        console.log(result.githubLink);
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
```

This is output from console.log(result)

```
{ _id: 593c35e6ed9581db3ef85d75,
firstname: 'MyName',
lastname: 'MyLastName',
jobtitle: 'Web Developer',
email: 'foo@example.com',
githubLink: 'https://github.com/myGithub' }
```

And this is result from console.log(result.firstname); and  console.log(result.githubLink);

```
MyName
undefined
```

Is this promise somehow messing up with this result? It's really weird because logging only the result shows my github link and logging the link says undefined.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any typos anywhere?

Comment: I have copied & pasted the "githubLink" from the output of console.log(result) and i have been staring this block of code for 30 minutes now. I dont think that it's a typo

Comment: Copy the actual lines of the code where you are doing the logging and also show the schema in your question.

Comment: Thank you Neil. I was copying my schema to here and noticed that i didn't have githubLink property there. How i can mark that as right answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have fields present in your database object that are not actually present in the Schema defined for the model, then they will still "log" but you cannot access the values of the property normally.

In most cases you really want to define the item properly in your schema:

```
githubLink: String
```

Or you can access properties you deliberately do not want to define using the [`.get()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-get) method:

```
result.get('githubLink')
```